# How to make this SQL query work? I wish to insert a tuple inside the query

Tags: python, sql-server, tuples

This is the original SQL query which worked for me

```
sql_text = """select * from (
SELECT pr.CLOSING_DATE, 
'M' + CAST(year(pr.FIRST_DAY_DEL)*12+month(pr.FIRST_DAY_DEL) - year(pr.CLOSING_DATE)*12-month(pr.CLOSING_DATE) as varchar(2)) as relative_product,
pr.SETTLEMENT_PRICE as value
FROM COMMON.dbo.MDC_FUTURES_V pr, COMMON.dbo.MDC_CAT_V d
WHERE pr.MDC_ID = d.MDC_ID AND pr.FIRST_DAY_DEL<=pr.CLOSING_DATE + 1000
AND pr.MDC_ID IN ('10006968')
AND pr.PERIOD='Monthly' 
) as data
PIVOT (AVG(VALUE) FOR  relative_product IN (
[M1],[M2],[M3],[M4],[M5],[M6],[M7],[M8]
)) AS pvtL
ORDER BY CLOSING_DATE DESC"""

data = pd.read_sql(sql_text, con)
```

As I need much more months in the future, so I tried to replace the ([M1],[M2],[M3],[M4],[M5],[M6],[M7],[M8]) with a tuple. I wrote below

```
lst_m36=[]
for i in range(1,9):
    lst_m36.append(f"[M{i}]")
tple36=tuple(lst_m36)
```

However when I try to insert the tuple tple36 in the SQL query, I tried different "" () position but it never works.

```
sql_text = """select * from (
SELECT pr.CLOSING_DATE, 
'M' + CAST(year(pr.FIRST_DAY_DEL)*12+month(pr.FIRST_DAY_DEL) - year(pr.CLOSING_DATE)*12-month(pr.CLOSING_DATE) as varchar(2)) as relative_product,
pr.SETTLEMENT_PRICE as value
FROM COMMON.dbo.MDC_FUTURES_V pr, COMMON.dbo.MDC_CAT_V d
WHERE pr.MDC_ID = d.MDC_ID AND pr.FIRST_DAY_DEL<=pr.CLOSING_DATE + 1000
AND pr.MDC_ID IN ('10006968')
AND pr.PERIOD='Monthly' 
) as data
PIVOT (AVG(VALUE) FOR  relative_product IN (tple36)) AS pvtL
ORDER BY CLOSING_DATE DESC"""
```

Here is the error message matching with the last query

> DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql: select * from (
> SELECT pr.CLOSING_DATE,
> 'M' + CAST(year(pr.FIRST_DAY_DEL)*12+month(pr.FIRST_DAY_DEL) - year(pr.CLOSING_DATE)*12-month(pr.CLOSING_DATE) as varchar(2)) as relative_product,
> pr.SETTLEMENT_PRICE as value
> FROM COMMON.dbo.MDC_FUTURES_V pr, COMMON.dbo.MDC_CAT_V d
> WHERE pr.MDC_ID = d.MDC_ID AND pr.FIRST_DAY_DEL<=pr.CLOSING_DATE + 1000
> AND pr.MDC_ID IN ('10006968')
> AND pr.PERIOD='Monthly'
> ) as data
> PIVOT (AVG(VALUE) FOR  relative_product IN (tple36)) AS pvtL
> ORDER BY CLOSING_DATE DESC
>
> ('08S01', '[08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Communication link failure (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')
> unable to rollback

Can anyone help with a SQL query that works?

Comment: Looks like SQL Server but the query is very hard to read. Whatever it tries to do doesn't need such complexity. What is the query trying to do?

Comment: Date-related queries become A LOT easier and orders of magnitude faster if you use a [Calendar Table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) - a table prepopulated with eg 20 years of dates with extra columns for year, month, week number,  month day, day of week etc with indexes on all columns that may be used for reporting. Join the Calendar table with your own table and aggregating by year or month becomes a simple `GROUP BY Calendar.Year, Calendar.Month` statement.

Comment: I believe that you can find the answer for the question will this work once you resolve the error here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=281f982a73b8d7d92c96fe22c9e0be88  Also, I believe you need to adress to the tuple with @ or something...

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos Thanks Kanavos, I have basically no knowledge so get the initial SQL query from a colleague, we are trying to retrieve the price forward curves for one asset and the M1 M2 are the monthly contract, compared to today

Comment: @VBoka Thanks, I was looking for something instead of () or f{}, I just tried "@tple36@" and "@tple36" but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Don't use pivot while query step. Get results and use the pandas package to get pivot. I think it is going to be easier.

Comment: Thanks Hasan, indeed this is a good idea which I haven't thought about! I am having a pomegranate juice from Turkey and here comes help from a Turkish, how impressive! :)

Comment: you can use a tsql cursor and dynamic sql to construct your pivot table sql, as you did in python then execute the sql

Comment: You are welcome @neutralname. If you come to Turkey, you would understand better. We are kind people. ;)